Microsoft Edge - when Webdriver is used (Selenium), app asks for MS Authenticator code but not for other methods of opening browser
I am testing a Microsoft Dynamics eCommerce application with Selenium but whenever I open the app through the webdriver, I am always prompted for an Authenticator code.
The application has Single Sign On applied and should go straight to the site, which works as expected outside of webdriver usage.
I tried various ways of opening the site, comparing the automated version with normal manual usage.
When used only during test automation (on webdriver), the user is prompted for a code generated by MS Authenticator app (on a mobile phone). Was expecting that user should arrive straight away at the site with no authentication required.
Summary of where site is working differently:
a) open app in Edge - opens as user logged in
b) open app in Edge InPrivate view - prompts for username and password
c) open app in Edge Webdriver - asks for code in Authenticator app (installed on mobile phone)
d) open in Chrome Webdriver or regular - user is prompted for username and password.
